# Remove Open and Close Parentheses from Sphinx Index

Tags: sphinx

I have a `regexp_filter` that looks for a pattern in my documents e..g

`regexp_filter=Bob Smith=>Robert Smith`

However I've found this does not work when the pattern text is inside parentheses e.g..

`he and my boss (Bob Smith) were due to..`

I have tried a few things to get rid of the `(`

1. Added `(` to the Stopwords
2. Added a custom charset that does NOT include parens

But regardless patterns are not matched when they are inside parentheses.

Is there anyway to do this correctly?

Update is that precisely the same thing happens with hyphens.  Even if I explicitly remove them in `Stopwords` or `Charset` or even make a regexp to remove them

`regexp_filter=-=>`

They get indexed and break any regexps especially with word boundaries.

So:

`regepx_filter=\bBob\b=>Robert`

Fails in text like 'Recipient: Bob-Mark-John`

`

Comment: Make sure there are no extra new lines (ie wrapping) in the source, eg if there is a newline between Bob and Smith, the regex would NOT match it. (the regexp_filter, is applies on the raw incomming text, NOT after its been standardised (tokenized) as per charset_table.

Answer (score 0):

If you add parentheses to charset_table(means it's a valid char just like 'a'), means (Bob Smith) becomes (Robert Smith).
'`Robert Smith`' will not match '`(Robert Smith)`'.  You can have this match only if you enable infixing and do a wildcard search (like '`*Robert Smith*`').

You should add special chars to chartset_table only if you know for sure you need them as valid characters used to construct words.

Comment: Yeah just found that out. The problem is no matter what I do with the hyphen it will not act as a word separator. I tried it as ignore_chars but found that that turns 'abc-def' into 'abcdef' vs what should be happening 'abc def' when the hyphen is *not* in the char_set. However clearly they hyphen is not acting as a word separator even though a) not in char_set b) not ignore_char.

Comment: ignore_chars takes out characters -  that means ignored char becomes "void", so characters before and after it are glued(!). ignore_chars are not word separators. Word separators are any characters not declared. If you use hyphen in search string  - try to escape it (because hyphen is a syntax operator).  What do you get in SHOW META?