# Hyphen not indexing correctly in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

This is similar to a question I [just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204475/remove-open-and-close-parentheses-from-sphinx-index/50212339#50212339) regarding parentheses but is specific enough I thought it made sense to post separately to avoid confusion.

I thought that Hyphens were treated as word separators in Sphinx and have been getting unexpected behavior regardless. I've tried various solutions like `char_set` and `ignore_chars` to no effect.

It seems to be a very specific situation, as follows:

I made a regexp_filter that pulls two specific words together in my titles into one e.g.

`regexp_filter=non binding=>nonbinding`

This works in titles like:

`A non binding agreement`

but as soon as a hyphen is before or after the term e.g.

`Discussion-non binding agreements`

`non binding-or-required agreements`

The regexp fails.

I'm unsure why as the hyphen should be treated as far as I know as word separator and/or empty spaace.

Comment: You should provide your config and a query/document pair that produces incorrect search results.

Comment: @hank 1 will do, let me just strip all the extraneous stuff out to simplify the review. thanks

Comment: one problem with removing 'extraneous' stuff, is you might actually be inadvertently removing something that IS relevant! In creating a simplified 'example' you might inadvertently be hiding the issue. Remove any passwords, hostnames, but usually best to provide TOO MUCH info, than too little.